# Javascript - temporary storage of large (> 10 MB) object data

Tags: javascript, serialization, crossfilter

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to cache a large object over a page reload. More specifically I have a large `crossfilter.js` object that I'd like to retain, since creating it takes a while. I couldn't find any native way to persist a `crossfilter.js` instance.

I know about the following generic options:

- Local storage/session storage. Problem: Apparently no objects bigger
  than 5 or 10 MB can be stored, and the ones I'm trying to cache are upwards of 10 MB.
- Abusing `window.name` for a serialized version of my object.
  Problem: While it works for classes I've written myself, trying to
  serialize and de-serialize the `crossfilter.js` instance or its
  groups/dimensions leads to exceptions; i. e. the internal state of the
  `crossfilter.js` instance is not maintained. I'm using https://github.com/hunterloftis/cryo for serialization.
- `IndexedDB`. Problem: Same as with `window.name` - I'd have to
  serialize my data, which I haven't found a feasible approach for yet. Also a bit of an overkill for my needs, I guess.

Summarized: I want to keep a particular complex object in memory after a page reload. Possible solutions would allow to

1. store complex objects/class instances (with methods) in the
   local/session storage with increased or no memory limits,
2. using a hack like dumping the object in `window.name`, but accepting a
   complex object without the need for serialization as necessary for
   `window.name` or
3. using native `crossfilter.js` functionality to dump/cache one of its   instances.

Any tips? Although a browser-independent version is preferred, a Chrome-specific solution will be accepted as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you not just tried `localStorage.setItem('crossfilter', crossfilter.Instance.toString());`? I mean there's not a lot we can do without _some_ examples?

Comment: Yes, I did. Caused an exception telling me that the object I was trying to store (13 MB) was too big for the quota. What kind of examples would you consider to be helpful? There's nothing special about my use case except that the object to store is too large, hence I didn't include any code.

Comment: Okay, so there's a few options that you could take, you _could_ rely on the back end to cache the instance? If not, you _could_ also consider making some sort of hybrid web app, although probably not the best solution, you _could_ also try some sort of string compression algorithm? You could even try using something like getting the user to give permission to the app to store it as a string within a file? Although that approach isn't recommended **at all**.

Comment: Having done some _very_ quick and not what I'd call reliable math, if your compression algorithm is about 30% efficient, you _could_ in theory compress it down to ~8.75MB, which would allow you to use local storage.

Comment: (1) A back end solution / dumping the object to file would require serializing the object as well, wouldn't it? (2) A compression algorithm would again depend on having a serialized version of my object which. This is not a feasible option, since deserialization fails.

Comment: For the back end solution, which I **would recommend** doing in this case, you could just use a tostring implementation, that way the server doesn't have to do anything apart from storing a string somehow (session, text file, db, etc.), the only form of processing then is when the client gets the stored instance, but apart from that, there _shouldn't_ be a need for any form of serializing. Even when the client **does** get the instance back, you can just pass in the string into a function object I guess, rather than relying on something as temperamental as `eval`?

Comment: Most crossfilter data can be serialized with plain old [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). It's true, crossfilter's internal state is not serializable; you'd have to serialize the data that you input to the `crossfilter()` function.

Comment: @Gordon That's what I'd like to avoid, since it takes a while for crossfilter to process the data - the data set is sizeable, and I have a lot of dimensions and groups. That's why I'd ideally want to dump the crossfilter state _after_ the data has been processed.

Comment: Got it. Yes, in theory it's maybe not the hardest thing in the world, since crossfilter is a pile of indices which all use efficient data structures like `Uint8Array` and very few pointers, but the library doesn't support it so you are looking at digging deep in the code and implementing it yourself. You could open an issue at [crossfilter/crossfilter](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter) if you want to discuss how to do this... but it's a serious effort. There are other issues like the fact that functions are not in general serializable if they use closures.

Comment: Maybe there is some way to pre-aggregate your data? That's usually the first option when trying to deal with huge data sets that are outside the natural limits of crossfilter (loosely speaking, trying to deal with more than 500K rows is going to cause pain).

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible - the pre-aggregation, that is. I was hoping for a native JS equivalent of Python's pickle, but I guess nothing like that exists (yet). I tried cryo (https://github.com/hunterloftis/cryo), which aims for that niche, but it didn't work for this particular problem either. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Link to [the enhancement request](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/issues/110).